# Cannot rewrite the rip even after disabling all the security features

Tags: exploit, buffer-overflow

I was trying to exploit a simple buffer overflow on a self created binary.
i have disabled all the security features by compiling with the flags -
**--fno-stack-protector -z execstack -no-pie**.
my program just copied data through gets on a defined variable.
however when i try to overwrite the RIP and check the crash point, i get this -
[image: dmesg | tail]

what can i do to overwrite the rip?

Comment: Hello and welcome to RE.SE! Please be more verbose. Paste your crash context - location, regs, stack under gdb - in text. Attaching the binary would be great ofc.

Comment: from your RIP (`0x41414141415d`) that you've managed to overwrite `rip`.

Comment: But shouldnt it be 0x414141414141 as i had only put A's

Comment: Can you just share program binary if it is ok?